Cross-referencing Images Between Website (CORS) Error
I am encountering an error when referencing an image, hosted on one of my websites, from another one.
Problem

Image is hosted on https://example1.com
Trying to reference image from https://example2.com by placing src="https://exmaple1.com/imaginaryPath/guest.png" in an <img> element.
Image doesn't appear. Console returns "Access to image at 'https://example1.com/imaginaryPath/guest.png' from 'EX.AM.PL.E/IP" origin "https://example2.com/" has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

.htaccess on https://example1.com/

(yes the root site directory, not a subdirectory.)

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"

Yes, httpd (Apache) reads the .htaccess per the rules in the .conf
Please help 
The console error
Tried:

Modifying Apache Configuration
Modifying Method of Referencing Image

Expected:

Image to Load
No Related Console Errors

EDIT:
The code provided is for the HTML image element. The CORS Policy errors are no longer occurring, but the image still does not appear. Additionally, the image, from the same exact URL, does load when simply navigating to it through a browser.
Code (image):
<img src="https://example1.com/imaginaryPath/guest.png" alt="Guest">


Unless you also use a crossorigin attribute on that img element, there should be no use for CORS in your scenario. Please clarify.

@jub0bs apologies, here is the img element code
<img src="https://example1.com/imaginaryPath/guest.png" alt="Guest">
and the image still does not load.

Is the image served with Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site or same-origin? (Although that would not explain the CORS error message.)

@HeikoTheißen, on the hosting site, or the referencing site? I've posted the code for both in the post, though it's not displaying the image despite the lack of CORS errors in the console now.

On the site hosting the image.
